# 2CO Dontate Button

Tags: php, asp.net, 2checkout

How can I make a 2CO donate button?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. 2Checkout does not allow donations. 
https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/prohibited.html

Answer (score 1):

2Checkout does allow donations as long as you are based in the United States and have 501c3 status. You can [contact 2Checkout directly](https://www.2checkout.com/contact/) if you have any questions on whether or not you will be allowed to use your account for donations. If you are approved, you can use a form that [allows the customer to enter in the donation amount](https://www.2checkout.com/blog/knowledge-base/merchants/tech-support/basic-integration/how-can-i-allow-the-customer-to-put-in-their-own-price/).